# SQL Agent can't run package with WMI Event Watcher Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, com, wmi, sql-agent

I created a SSIS package that watches for files being created on another server using a WMI Event Watcher Task.  This package works fine when I run it in VS.  It works fine when I manually Execute it from the Integration Services Catalog.  When I try to run it as a scheduled SQL Agent Job I get 
**Error: Watching for the Wql query caused the following system exception: "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))". Check the query for errors or WMI connection for access rights/permissions.**

My question is why does this not run as a SQL Agent Job when I can run it successfully several different ways?  Based on the error code seems to be a COM/DCOM security issue.

So far I have:

- Tried many web sites most are more or less like this
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-troubleshooting?redirectedfrom=MSDN  I have followed all the instructions on these websites with no change.
- Gone back and gave even more permissions then specified by the website to the COM Limits and DCOM Config of the Windows Management and Instrumentation.
- Have restarted the WMI service on the other server several times after each change.
- Tried SA and myself as owner of the Job.
- Tried my usual SQL Agent Proxy account and the default Server Agent Service Account (which is a Managed Service Account) as the Run As for the package.
- Tried running as a 32 and 64 bit runtimes.
- Have made the SQL Agent Proxy account and Server Agent Service Account Admins on the other server.
- Tried hard coding my user name and password into the Connection Manager and used Windows Authentication.

*** New tests ***

- Tested the SQL Agent Job using the File System as the package source instead of the SSIS Catalog, still failed with same error.
- Tested running package using the Execute Package Utility and it worked!

Comment: If you haven't tried check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fe033702-d1e9-4276-a2a4-99a7ae61c722/wql-wmi-event-watcher-task-access-denied?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Thanks @CR241 but that article points back to the same info as the sample link I had included, and to things I have already listed as tried.  No new info.

Comment: Have you also read through [Troubleshooting Problems with WMI Scripts and the WMI Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ff406382(v=msdn.10)) yet? In addition to all of the common WMI authentication issues the impersonated user probably also needs at least RX permissions on the remote folder/files being monitored.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have not seen that article but it does not address my problem or the error message (0x80070005) I am getting.  WMI is working and I can successfully run the package several ways, just not as a SQL Agent Job.  The accounts I am using are all Admins on the other server right now and the directory security is set so Everyone has full access to it because of a third party app that writes to it doesn't understand security.

Answer (score 0):

The AgentSqlServer user does not have rights to launch WMI Querys on server, You should create a proxy account and join it à to the step on the SQL Job.